# How to use RxJava to make multiple thread to run sequentially

Tags: multithreading, rx-java, rx-java2

Assume that there are 3 threads, T1, T2, T3.
How can I make them run sequentially, say, the execution order is T1, T2, T3, T1, T2, T3 ...
Could we use RxJava to implement it?

Could it be possible that there are 3 threads and separately print out T1, T2 or T3, and we can print out T1 T2 T3 sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Observable.concat(request1, request2, request3)`, which will execute requests sequentially:

```
Observable<String> r1 = getObs().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
Observable<String> r2 = getObs().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
Observable<String> r3 = getObs().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

Observable<String> result = Observable.concat(r3, r2, r1);
```

Or, if request need a result from previuous request - use `flatMap`:

```
request1()
        .flatMap(d -> request2(d))
        .flatMap(d -> request3(d))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe();
```

Comment: Thanks, I will have a try.  If it works, I will immediately accept it as the right answer.

Comment: AndroidSchedulers is used in Android project, it is just a Java program.
Could you implement it only in Java?
Could you provide an executable java code to better express how to do it?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no built-in Scheduler for main thread in Java because there's no built-in mechanism for multi-thread synchronization in Java (like there is e.g. `Looper` in Android) . You could either use a `blockingSubsrcibe()` call from the main thread if that is applicable in your case or you have to manually synchronize and offload the subscription method to main thread.

Comment: @nstosic thanks, could you please provide any code snippet to make me understand it better?